# g++ not finding opencv .hpp files

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I am trying to use g++ (from within Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10) to compile a .cpp file that imports OpenCV header files.

When `g++ main.cpp` didn't work, I searched here and found people recommending the use of `-I` to designate the path to the include files.

I have tried `-I/path/to/opencv/include` as a flag to my g++ command, but still receive the same error.

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out why g++ is not finding the `.hpp` files...

---

**Minimal code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

**Error received:**

```
No such file or directory
    2 | #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

---

**Edit:**

@KonradRudolph advised that I should not have a `/` between the `-I` flag and my include path. Replacing it with a space now yields a different error:

```
In file included from C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core.hpp:3307,
                 from main.cpp:2:
C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:717:14: error: 'recursive_mutex' in namespace 'std' does
not name a type
  717 | typedef std::recursive_mutex Mutex;
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:63:1: note: 'std::recursive_mutex' is defined in header
<mutex>'; did you forget to '#include <mutex>'?
   62 | #include <mutex>  // std::mutex, std::lock_guard
  +++ |+#include <mutex>
   63 | #endif
C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:718:29: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
  718 | typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
      |                             ^~~~~
C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:718:29: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:718:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  718 | typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;
      |                                  ^
```

Comment: Interesting that code that includes `opencv2/core.hpp` makes the compiler complain about `opencv/core.hpp`... ;) (well, not really, more likely you didn't check that your minimal code actually reproduces the problem)

Comment: @DanMašek I typed the error by hand because I'm working from a different computer, and I missed the "2". Fixed. And of course I checked if my minimal code produces the error.

Comment: @avi You can try `"opencv2/core.hpp"` if it works

Comment: Hi @nhatnq. I just tried -- receiving the same error (only now with quotation marks instead of carats).

Comment: Have you checked whether the core.hpp actually exists in the include path or not ??

Comment: @nhatnq Yes. I have all of the main .hpp files (incl. core, imgproc, etc.) in the directory: `C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2`. When I add the `-I` tag to the g++ command I write it as `-I/C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include`.

Comment: Seems the path is not correct. Does Window use \ ??

Comment: @nhatnq I don't quite understand your question, could you explain what you mean? Since `/opencv2` is under `/include`, the compiler should be able to find `<opencv/core.hpp>` with the flag that I added.

Comment: @nhatnq Both `\ ` and `/` work. I don’t think g++ needs `/` between `-I` and the path but I’m not a frequent user of mingw and it shouldn’t hurt.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks for the reply! Getting a different error now, which means progress? Looks like you were right about the `/`. I removed it and now I receive an error about mutex -- which I am not familiar with. 

`C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:718:29: error: 'Mutex' is not a member of 'cv'
C:/Users/USER/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:718:34: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  718 | typedef std::lock_guard<cv::Mutex> AutoLock;`

Comment: @KonradRudolph I updated my original post with the full new error... If you get a minute would you mind taking a look? As far as I understand, Mutex deals with thread permissions... not really sure why the compilation is getting stuck on that.

Comment: This seems to be a known error with your version of MinGW. See here for a workaround: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10272#issuecomment-357467021

Comment: @KonradRudolph I appreciate your effort. The download link in that guide is for a .zip folder, and as such I am not quite sure what the poster means by `4.) Understand the option "Threads", chose "posix".` He seems to be referring to an option on a GUI installer, so I tried installing MinGW with the installation manager, but can't find any sort of option related to "Threads". Stumped!

Comment: @KonradRudolph solved the issue. Adding answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The initial error was being caused because I had a `/` between the `-I` flag and my include path. Replacing this with a space led to another error...

In an attempt to solve the error involving "mutex" (see edit of original post), I attempted to follow [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10272#issuecomment-357467021) workaround. Note that step 4 is no longer relevant, as (at the time of this post) the download link leads to a `.zip` file.

In order to configure the "Threads" option, I downloaded the installer using [this guide](https://cpp.tutorials24x7.com/blog/how-to-install-mingw-on-windows). This version of the installer gave the option to select "posix" under Threads, as the workaround suggested.

After installation (and adding `/bin` from the new mingw-w64 folder to PATH), I am now able to successfully compile my example code.